# How to check to see if Ruby-Kafka retries works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, ruby-kafka

In the documentation it is mentioned that producer retries to send the message to the queue based on `max_retries`.

So I shutdown the Kafka and then tried my producer. I get this error

```
Fetching cluster metadata from kafka://localhost:9092
[topic_metadata] Opening connection to localhost:9092 with client id MYCLIENTID
ERROR -- : [topic_metadata] Failed to connect to localhost:9092: Connection refused
DEBUG -- : Closing socket to localhost:9092
ERROR -- : Failed to fetch metadata from kafka://localhost:9092
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 486ms (ActiveRecord: 33.9ms)
```

which it make sense, however the `retries` never happens after that. I have read the doc inside-out and I can't figure it out how this `retries` actually going to trigger?

Here is my code:

```
 def self.deliver_message(kafka, message, topic, transactional_id)
      producer = kafka.producer(idempotent: true,
                                transactional_id: transactional_id,
                                required_acks: :all,
                                max_retries: 5,
                                retry_backoff: 5)
      producer.produce(message, topic: topic)
      producer.deliver_messages
    end
```

link to doc:

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-kafka/Kafka/Producer#initialize-instance_method

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retries are based on the type of Exception thrown by the producer callback. According to the [Callback Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback.html) there are the following Exception possible happening during callback:

> The exception thrown during processing of this record. Null if no error occurred. Possible thrown exceptions include:
>
> Non-Retriable exceptions (fatal, the message will never be sent):

- InvalidTopicException
- OffsetMetadataTooLargeException
- RecordBatchTooLargeException
- RecordTooLargeException
- UnknownServerException

> Retriable exceptions (transient, may be covered by increasing #.retries):

- CorruptRecordException
- InchvalidMetadataException
- NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppendException
- NotEnoughReplicasException
- OffsetOutOfRangeException
- TimeoutException
- UnknownTopicOrPartitionException

Shutting down Kafka completely rather looks like a non-retriable Exception.